# Removing entries from SharedPreferences - Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm creating an array from stored SharedPreferences. The code below takes the most recent five and creates an array (so I can work with it). The problem is my `editor.remove` statment doesn't remove the Shared entry but rather just sets it to null. I can't create the most recent 5 entries. How do you delete the first entry if it list is greater than 5 and add a new one to the end? (This will be sort of like a most recent saved searches list).

I know an alternative is to use JSON. Can you point to an example? Thanks.

```
public boolean savedIPsArray(String oneTimeData, String key, Context mContext) {   
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0); 

    int size = prefs.getInt(key+"_size", 0);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); 

    if(size < 5){
        editor.putString(key+ "_" + size, oneTimeData);   
        editor.putInt(key+"_size", ++size); 
    }
    else{
        editor.remove(key+ "_" + 0).commit();
        editor.putString(key+ "_" + (size-1), oneTimeData);
        editor.putInt(key+"_size", size);
    }

    return editor.commit();
}

public String[] loadedIPsArray(String key, Context mContext) {  
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
    int size = prefs.getInt(key+ "_size", 0);  
    array = new String[size];  
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  {
        array[i] = prefs.getString(key+ "_" + i, null);  
    }
    return array;  
}
```

Comment: I'd consider using a database instead.  You can perform an automatic trim to X rows, and you won't have to manage your string magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to convert some of those `int`'s to `String`'s:

```
if(size < 5){
    editor.putString(key+ "_" + String.valueOf(size), oneTimeData);   
    editor.putInt(key+"_size", ++size); 
}
else{
    editor.remove(key+ "_" + String.valueOf(0)).commit();
    editor.putString(key+ "_" + String.valueOf(size-1), oneTimeData);
    editor.putInt(key+"_size", size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Track last added index as well as total size, then after the max size is reached, loop around, overwriting the earlier keys instead of removing them.  Since you know the total size and the last added entry, you can then retrieve the keys in oldest to newest order by retrieving them in order from last_added+1 to size, then from 0 to last_added.